# Google Sign In Button Branding Styles in Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, google-signin

I have followed this [expo-google-app-auth](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google/) and using the authentication in the react native app.

```
const { type, accessToken, user } = await Google.logInAsync(config);
```

With this, I am taking `accessToken` and passing it to the `node.js` which has firebase integration

```
var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);
```

Everything works fine here, now my question is I want to use the GoogleSignIn Branding Button. For me, just the normal button is sufficient enough without any google library for adding button. Is there any styles alone to integrate it into the normal button?

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge, expo doesn't provide branded google sign in button like react-native-cli. But you can use react-native-elements library. There is a built in component with the name social icon and you just need to pass google as type. More explanation can be found [here](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/social_icon.html).

thanks

Comment: Unfortunately there seems to be no way to configure the Social Icon component to respect [Google branding guidelines](https://developers.google.com/identity/branding-guidelines) therefore this is not a viable option.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer mentioned, expo doesn't have a built-in branded Google Sign-In button.

My strategy was to use an Icon button, which is found in the `@expo/vector-icons` package. FontAwesome5 has a Google icon, and this gives you an easy and customizable way to create a button that matches the branding.

Assuming you're already importing and using basic react-native functions like Text, your code might look something like this:

```js
import { FontAwesome5 } from '@expo/vector-icons';

// your code... 

<FontAwesome5.Button style={styles.googleButton} name="google" onPress={() => this.googleLogIn()}
        //any other customization you want, like borderRadius, color, or size
>
  <Text style={styles.googleText}>Log In With Google</Text>
</FontAwesome5.Button>
```

Here is the relevant section in the documentation: https://docs.expo.io/guides/icons/#button-component

By the way, it doesn't matter if you use `FontAwesome` or `FontAwesome5` or `Ionicons` or any other Icon library included in `@expo/vector-icons`. They all have this button component. You can see the list of Icons here: https://icons.expo.fyi/

Comment: Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to set the rainbow like color that follows the Google guidelines.